# URLWithInboundURL strange behaviour dependant on app state

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an issue where I am using FBSDK AppInvites and the use of the link causing some irritating behaviour...

Scenario 1 (WORKING): I have the Facebook app installed on my iPhone and the user receives the app invite I have sent from my app on another device. As Its not in App Store I do not tap the link in the App Invite yet but I run my app from Xcode on my iPhone.  After its built and is now running I press the home button on my iPhone and the go to the FB app and tap the AppInvite link. My app reopens and I then login with FBSDK Login.  After the login I run a method to check the app Invite link for a embedded referral code and then run some stuff that prints to a Label!  ALL WORKS!

Scenario 2 (NOT WORKING): I do all of the above however after I build/run the app from Xcode and its now on my device I stop Xcode running the app and the app closes on my iPhone. I then go into the FB app and tap on the app invite which opens my app.  I login with FBSDK Login and all is good, but nothing is printed to the label.

Scenario 3 (Working): I do scenario 2 again but BEFORE I open the FB app and tap the AppInvite I open my app and then press the Home button on my iPhone. I then open FB and tap the AppInvite link and login with FBSDK Login and the Label is filled!

HOLY COW what on earth is happening!? I am sure I am missing a method in the app delegate somewhere for opening the app in a specific state but I am currently in a complete pickle that I can't see the wood for the trees!

This is the code in my app delegate that handles this:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[backendless initApp:APP_ID secret:SECRET_KEY version:VERSION_NUM];
[backendless.messaging registerForRemoteNotifications];
[backendless.userService setStayLoggedIn:YES];

@try {
    [backendless initAppFault];

}
@catch (Fault *fault) {
    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: %@", fault);
}
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];



}


-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

}

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
```

}

I then run through the below method which works, as I say when the app is in a running state but in the background but not from when its a fresh launch.  The code is basically retrieving the URL and the referral code and then using it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

Comment: More on this as I have now taken more time to investigate but STILL NEED HELP...

If I tap the APP INVITE in the FB app when my target app is in a non active start (not running in background) the app opens but the URL is not passed into the openUrl method!  Why is this?